# DB2 backup with BLOB fields

Tags: sql, db2, database-backups

**We use IBM DB2 10.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2**

**Majority of the DB2 space is occupied by fields of the type BLOB and CLOB.** 
Currently, full backup of the entire database takes very long time and goes beyond time limits. 
We tried to use incremental backup to speed up backup, but problem did not go away as BLOB and CLOB fields are still 
being pulled into the backup, irrespective of whether they were changed, so it is almost the same as doing a full backup.

**We decided to proceed with following approach:**
Create a new tablespace and put there tables with BLOBs and CLOBs. Old data will be archived once a year, and this tablespace every day.
Once the size of tablespace exceeds a certain limit, we will create a new space and start writing new data to it, and so on.

Problem occurs with restoration when using above mentioned approach.

**Offline backup steps:**

1. Full backup of all data is done.

   *DB2 -svl%LOG% BACKUP DATABASE %DB_NAME% TO %DB_PATH_BACKUP% COMPRESS EXCLUDE LOGS WITHOUT PROMPTING*
2. Logs are copied.
3. Backup of a separate tablespace is done.

   *B2 -svl%LOG% BACKUP DATABASE %DB_NAME% TABLESPACE (TSPACEGEN1) TO %DB_PATH_BACKUP% COMPRESS EXCLUDE LOGS WITHOUT PROMPTING*
4. Logs are copied.

**Restoration approach:**

5. Full backup is restored.

   *RESTORE DB EAPOBLOB FROM "..." TAKEN AT ... REPLACE HISTORY FILE WITHOUT PROMPTING*
6. Logs are copied and ROLLFORWARD performed. So far everything is OK.

   *ROLLFORWARD DATABASE COMMDB TO END OF LOGS*
7. Backup of a separate tablespace is restored. 
   RESTORE DATABASE EAPOBLOB TABLESPACE (TSPACEGEN1 ) FROM "..." TAKEN AT  WITHOUT PROMPTING
8. Logs are copied and ROLLFORWARD performed. So far everything is OK.

   *ROLLFORWARD DATABASE COMMDB TO END OF LOGS*

**!! when we try to connect to DB:**
The following errors were received: 
A connection attempt was unsuccessful.
Summary
**SQL1117N  A connection to or activation of the database cannot be made because of ROLLFORWARD PENDING.**

**Is this feasible approach for backup and are steps we take to backup and restore adequate?
Is there a better way to speed up backup, while still maintaining same level of resilience?**

Comment: Edit your question to add all these facts (1) Db2-server operating system (2) DB2 version and fixpack (3) the exact command line for the Db2-backup  (4) whether the tables have a dedicated LONG tablespace *per table* (which is a pre-req for incremental backups of lob data to have any noticeable performance difference).

Comment: It appears you are using a shared tablespace for the long data. For best results with incremental backups, any table that has lob/blob/clob columns should have a *dedicated* (i.e for sole use by that table alone) "LONG IN..." tablespace.